# Information with no reference in literature review

Tags: phd, citations, thesis

I am writing a literature review and I've found information in a thesis written in the literature review in a paragraph with no source, just ending with full stop. While at the end of the whole paragraph and after three full stops there is a cited source. How to cite the information with no source? Does that mean it belongs to the author who wrote that thesis or the whole paragraph belong to the source at the end? I am a little lost..

Comment: Is it feasible to read the cited source? Is the information from there?

Comment: unfortunately no its belong to a website asking for a credit to see the original source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're confused about whether information comes from a citation, the clear solution is to go to the source being cited and look for it there.

You will then find that one of two cases applies:

- Yes, the information was in the source, and the citation was just confusing. Now you've read the source yourself and can cite it in a less confusing manner.
- No, the information was not in the source, and you have no idea where it came from. Then the author either made a mistake or was dishonest. At this point, you either need to disregard the information as unreliable and unsourced or else try to contact the author to get a source.